# 500 : Internal Server Error in Jupyter Notebok

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have created a new environment for my project. When I try to access jupyter notebook from base environment it works fine. But when I launch it from the newly created environment I get this internal server error. This is the error message I get

```
[I 12:05:25.594 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 12:05:25.597 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Mr
[I 12:05:25.597 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 12:05:25.597 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=4cd895da9ce9853ab48b1bd1ddf318cbf2aea15e78bccf22
[I 12:05:25.597 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=4cd895da9ce9853ab48b1bd1ddf318cbf2aea15e78bccf22
[I 12:05:25.597 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:05:25.665 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///C:/Users/Mr/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2856-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8889/?token=4cd895da9ce9853ab48b1bd1ddf318cbf2aea15e78bccf22
or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=4cd895da9ce9853ab48b1bd1ddf318cbf2aea15e78bccf22
[E 12:05:30.910 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Untitled.ipynb (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
result = await result
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 775, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(value)
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 101, in get
get_frontend_exporters=get_frontend_exporters
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 512, in render_template
return template.render(**ns)
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "page.html" %}
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
{% block header %}
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 115, in block "header"
{% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
File "C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\carflask\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 23, in get_frontend_exporters
from nbconvert.exporters.base import get_export_names, get_exporter
File "C:\Users\Mr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\nbconvert\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .exporters import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbconvert.exporters'
[E 12:05:30.927 NotebookApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8889",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8889/tree",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cookie": "_xsrf=2|7daefccd|f38abab2a3ef7700b83bd2ee64c5f842|1606195796; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1606199381|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ZDIzODY0YmZkYmVkNGQ4YWFhMzA5ZTkyNzYzMDEyMGU=|cffedb3214a6885e560a4b66e697de4990c13fc43ce89a1a899915b331d728c9\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1606199727|23:username-localhost-8889|44:MTA0YzI0MzY2OTlkNDExNzhhOGUwNzA4NWNkZWUxNTM=|7676b32691b3aa30171939b49a95c7a706b0aac9854fd638c464b069984bd5b2\""
}
[E 12:05:30.928 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/Untitled.ipynb (::1) 110.72ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree
```

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading jupyter hub first

- **pip install --upgrade jupyterhub**
- **pip install --upgrade --user nbconvert**

worked for me on windows 10 as well.